# HTML form not submitting using python flask

Tags: python, html, flask, post

Would you know why doesn't this HTML form submit?
I just do not get the "POST" message in Flask and therefore cannot execute what I want from there.

HTML part (with a button that "unhides" the test)

```
            <button id="take_test" class="btn btn-info" onclick="Showtest()">Take the test</button>

            <form style="visibility:hidden" id="addiction2" action:"/test" method:"post">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group1">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you experience an impaired control over gaming (frequency, intensity, duration, termination, context)?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group1" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group1" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group2">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you experience an increasing priority given to gaming to the extent that gaming takes precendence over other life interests and daily activities?:</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group2" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group2" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group3">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you experience a continuation or escalation of gaming despite the occurance of negative consequences (i.e. significant impairment in personal, family, social, educational, occupational or other important areas of functioning)?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group3" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group3" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group4">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you try to stop gaming or reduce the time spent gaming, but failed to do that?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group4" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group4" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group5">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you ever lie to your spouse, family or friends about the amount of time you have spent gaming?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group5" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group5" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </main>

            <script>
            function Showtest() {
                var x = document.getElementById("addiction2");
                x.style.visibility = "visible";
                var y = document.getElementById("take_test");
                y.style.display = "none";
                var z = document.getElementById("footer");
                z.style.display = "block";
            }
            </script>
```

Python part where I am trying to use the post method to add the variables into a score (I know this can probably be done in a smarter way, but for now even the POST is not being received (as the logs show) and the redirect does not happen)

```
@app.route("/test", methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def test():
    if request.method == "POST":

        #get all the answers, store them in variables as 1 or 0
        q1 = request.form['group1']
        q2 = request.form['group2']
        q3 = request.form['group3']
        q4 = request.form['group4']
        q5 = request.form['group5']

        score = q1+q2+q3+q4+q5

        print(score)

        #mark database as test completed for this user

        return redirect("/results")
```

Comment: The `action` and `method` attributes of your `form` element have colons instead of equals signs. Could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the POST URL using `url_for` handler.

```
 <form style="visibility:hidden" id="addiction2" action="{{ url_for('test') }}" method="post">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group1">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you experience an impaired control over gaming (frequency, intensity, duration, termination, context)?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group1" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group1" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group2">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you experience an increasing priority given to gaming to the extent that gaming takes precendence over other life interests and daily activities?:</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group2" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group2" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group3">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you experience a continuation or escalation of gaming despite the occurance of negative consequences (i.e. significant impairment in personal, family, social, educational, occupational or other important areas of functioning)?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group3" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group3" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group4">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you try to stop gaming or reduce the time spent gaming, but failed to do that?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group4" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group4" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <fieldset id:"group5">
                    <p>Over the last 12 months, did you ever lie to your spouse, family or friends about the amount of time you have spent gaming?</p>
                    <input type="radio" id="1" name="group5" value="1" required>
                    <label for="1">Yes</label><br>
                    <input type="radio" id="0" name="group5" value="0" required>
                    <label for="0">No</label><br>
                    </fieldset>
                </div>
                <br>
                <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="submit">Submit</button>
                </form>
            </main>

            <script>
            function Showtest() {
                var x = document.getElementById("addiction2");
                x.style.visibility = "visible";
                var y = document.getElementById("take_test");
                y.style.display = "none";
                var z = document.getElementById("footer");
                z.style.display = "block";
            }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how to do a simple form in flask. You'll need to install the `Flask-WTF` package.
Link to the doc with all the available fields: [link](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/fields/#basic-fields)

```py
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import PasswordField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length

class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
    # create password entry box
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(4, 32)])
    # create submit button
    submit = SubmitField("Login")

@app.route("/login", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def auth_user():
    form = LoginForm() # load form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        # do something if form submitted
        if form.password.data == "your password":
           print("logged in!")
    else:
        # else sent form
        return flask.render_template("login.html", form=form)
```

and the html related page

```html
<html>
    <body>
        <div>
            <form method="POST" action="">
                {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Log in</legend>
                    <div>
                        {{ form.password.label }}
                        {{ form.password }}
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div>
                    {{ form.submit }}
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: But is flask_wtf mandatory for a form to submit?
I have other pages (login, logout, change password, etc.) that work perfectly fine without flask WTF and only this one is failing. And I can't seem to understand why.
For example, this one does a perfectly fine post:

<...>
{% block main %}
    <form action="/change_pass" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input class="form-control" name="old_password" placeholder="Old password" type="text" required>
        </div>
<...>

Comment: no of course not but i found it really useful as i'm not a web developer

Answer (score 0):

FOUND IT! A typo (using : instead of =) - that's all it was.

What I had:

```
<form style="visibility:hidden" id="addiction2" action:"/test" method:"post">
```

What I needed to have:

```
<form style="visibility:hidden" id="addiction2" action="/test" method=:"post">
```

Thanks all for help!